# How to get a triangle of O's

Tags: python

I am trying to create a "text triangle" consisting of the character `'o'`. Here is the code I wrote:

```
base = 6
print("Part Two: Triangle with o's")
for r in range(base, 0, -1):
    for c in range(r):
        print(' ', end='')
    print('o', sep='')
```

The code that I wrote is outputting this:

```
      o
     o
    o
   o
  o
 o
```

but my desired output is this:

```
     o
    oo
   ooo
  oooo
 ooooo
oooooo
```

Could someone please help me identify what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Perhaps you should copy-paste your code into the question instead of showing us a picture of it.

Comment: please submit the content of your images as code in your post

Comment: Has your teacher given you permission to find help online? Because they have a lot of tools at their disposal to find students trying to cheat.

Comment: I'm sorry about that. I am extremely new to this site and its privileges

Answer (score -1):

Here's a function to do it:

```
def text_triangle(base, char):
    return '\n'.join(' ' * (base-i) + char * i for i in range(1, base+1))

print(text_triangle(6, 'o'))
```

Not going to hold the fact that you just posted a screenshot against you because this question has a lot to do with formatting, which is difficult to represent in markdown.

**EDIT**

You got the correct number of spaces on each line (good job!). The problem with your code was that you were only putting a single `'o'` on each line instead of filling the rest of the line with `'o'`'s.

```
base = 6
for r in range(base-1, -1, -1):
    for blank in range(0, r):
        print(' ', end='')
    for o in range(r, base):
        print('o', end='')
    print()
```

To do that, we can just write another nested for-loop that picks up where the last nested for-loop left off, at `r`, and go until the end of the line, `base`. Finally, we need to call `print()` with no arguments at the bottom of the main for-loop to get a newline character. I hope this is more explanatory than my quick answer before.

The above fits your teacher's requirements, but is far from the best solution. If I had to answer this question without any restrictions (i.e. using nested for-loops), I would probably do something like this:

```
base = 6
for r in range(base):
    print('{:>{}}'.format('o' * (r+1), base))
```

This solution uses [`str.format()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) and the [format specification mini-language](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatspec) to right align the `'o'`'s.

Comment: Would the downvoters care to explain what is wrong with my answer? It produced the exact output that the OP desired in a fairly efficient manner.

Comment: Perhaps because you are answering what appears to be a *"do my homework for me"* question by giving a code dump with no explanation of why it works and what was wrong with the code in the question.How will the asker learn how to program from this answed?

Comment: The answer has to use strictly for loops. And I would actually like to be guided in the right direction instead of just being given the answer.

Comment: Just edited my answer to flesh it out a little bit more. Sorry that it took so long for me to get around to it. Looking back, I agree with @AdrianHHH that my answer was a bit of a code dump, but I believe I have now given sufficient explanation. Additionally, I have included a "for-loop only" solution, as the OP requested.